# python round function

Tags: python

While executing the following command:

```
percent_2 = (round(percent_1, 1)).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

the following error occured:

> "{0}".format(str(converter))) TypeError: cannot convert the series to
>   .

What is it happening?

Comment: Is your `percent_1` a string, a numpy array, or a dataframe? where the `round` function is coming from?

Comment: Much would be made clear if you showed a [mcve].

Comment: @anishtain [round](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) is a built-in function in Python.

Comment: @JackTaylor Numpy also has round function, but there's not enough code to figure out where is it coming from

Answer (score 0):

this is slightly unclear: I'm not certain if you would like to round a float in which case you would use:

```
percent_2 = round(percent_1, 1)
```

if you would like to round and sort every element in an array:

```
percent_1.sort()
for element in percent_1:
    percent_1[element] = round(percent_1[element], 1)
```